# wrong constant name in Object.const_set with nested module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a bunch of modules I'd like to define in a namespace, I put them in an initializer, but I'm getting a 'wrong constant name' exception:

```
# this is a self-contained example
require 'active_support/all'
# ==> true

[:baz, :qux].each do |name|
  Object.const_set("FooBar::#{name.to_s.camelize}", Module.new {
    define_singleton_method :my_awesome_static_method do |amount|
      DoSomething.calculate(amount)
    end
  })
end
# =NameError: wrong constant name FooBar::Baz
# = from (irb):4:in `const_set'
# = from (irb):4:in `block in irb_binding'
# = from (irb):3:in `each'
# = from (irb):3
# = from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I think that I am getting this because the initializer runs before `FooBar` is defined, but the problem is that if I define it in this initializer, `FooBar.constants` is empty, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in the `Foobar` class or module:

```
module Foobar
  %w[Baz Qux].each do |name|
    const_set(name, Module.new {
      define_singleton_method :my_awesome_static_method do |amount|
        DoSomething.calculate(amount)
      end
    })
  end
end
```

use `class Foobar` if it's class.

This won't redefine it or anything, just open it for adding new classes in its namespace. Notice how I removed Object and Foobar from the `const_set` and used Ruby's `%w[]` notation to define an array of strings, no need to `to_s` and `camelize` them now.

Also, the reason it wasn't working for you was both the use of the colons in the constant name and the fact that you were defining the constants on Object by doing `Object.const_set` rather than defining them on Foobar. This will also work:

```
%w[Baz Qux].each do |name|
  Foobar.const_set(name, Module.new {
    define_singleton_method :my_awesome_static_method do |amount|
      DoSomething.calculate(amount)
    end
  })
end
```

Assuming Foobar is already defined, the previous example will work even if Foobar hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: I see, I had two things wrong, `const_set` is being sent to `FooBar`, not `Object`, and the name doesn't include colons.

Answer (score 4):

Your constant name contains colons. That's not allowed in a constant name.